# How to detect cycles in directory traversal

Tags: python

I am using Python on Ubuntu (Linux). I would also like this code to work on modern-ish Windows PCs. I can take or leave Macs, since I have no plan to get one, but I am hoping to make this code as portable as possible.

I have written some code that is supposed to traverse a directory and run a test on all of its subdirectories (and later, some code that will do something with each file, so I need to know how to detect links there too).

I have added a check for symlinks, but I do not know how to protect against hardlinks that could cause infinite recursion. Ideally, I'd like to also protect against duplicate detections in general (root: [A,E], A: [B,C,D], E: [D,F,G], where D is the same file or directory in both A and E).

My current thought is to check if the path from the root directory to the current folder is the same as the path being tested, and if it isn't, skip it as an instance of a cycle. However, I think that would take a lot of extra I/O or it might just retrace the (actually cyclic) path that was just created.

How do I properly detect cycles in my filesystem?

```py
    def find(self) -> bool:
        if self._remainingFoldersToSearch:
            current_folder = self._remainingFoldersToSearch.pop()
            if not current_folder.is_symlink():
                contents = current_folder.iterdir()
                try:
                    for item in contents:
                        if item.is_dir():
                            if item.name == self._indicator:
                                potentialArchive = [x.name for x in item.iterdir()]
                                if self._conf in potentialArchive:
                                    self._archives.append(item)
                                    if self._onArchiveReadCallback:
                                        self._onArchiveReadCallback(item)
                            else:
                                self._remainingFoldersToSearch.append(item)
                            self._searched.append(item)
                            if self._onFolderReadCallback:
                                self._onFolderReadCallback(item)
                except PermissionError:
                    logging.info("Invalid permissions accessing folder:", exc_info=True)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Most systems forbid hard links to directories precisely to avoid this nonsense.  Given that, do you care?

Comment: Directories can't usually be hard linked. You can't really distinguish which are the hard linked files, but you can see if a pair of files in different places are actually the same file (which implies one was hard linked) by comparing [`os.stat_result.st_ino`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result) for each.

Comment: @Ouroborus So, would keeping a table of the file inodes that way and comparing them detect all forms of cycles in the file tree? I see that this differs based on operating system, but if I don't store them outside of the scan it should be fine. I don't see Mac support listed, though - does it follow Linux rules or do they do something different?

Comment: Because you can't hard link directories, you can't get cycles that way.